# MySQLi select from two table with limit

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been try to combine two tables from `mysql` database, the two tables are `status and status_reply` both have the same columns number and name, that is `id, account_name, author, postdate, data` Please a help will be appreciated.

```
            $limit = "LIMIT 0, 10";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, "(SELECT * `status` as type from status WHERE data LIKE '%".$tag."%' ORDER BY postdate DESC $limit)
                                    UNION (SELECT * `status_reply` as type from status_reply WHERE data LIKE '%".$tag."%' ORDER BY postdate DESC $limit)");

            //$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM status WHERE data LIKE '%$tag%' ORDER BY postdate DESC $limit");
            $statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $statusid = $row["id"];
            $account_name = $row["account_name"];
            $author = $row["author"];
            $postdate = $row["postdate"];
            $data = $row["data"];
            $data = nl2br($data);
            $data = str_replace("&amp;","&",$data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $statuslist .= '<div id="status_'.$statusid.'" class="status_boxes"><div><b>Ivotised by <a href="home.php?u='.$author.'">'.$author.'</a> '.$postdate.':</b>
<article>'.$data.'</article>
</div></div>';
            }
```

Comment: and what problem do you have?

Comment: Dont use single quotes for delimiters,use backticks \`status\` Also you need a comma after *

Comment: Do you need to join them, using a column?

Comment: I want to retrieve the information from each table if tag is search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I have to remove the type in both status and status_reply as references to the tables and identified each of the columns by their names. Am curious about it too!

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, "
(SELECT id, account_name, author, postdate, data from status WHERE data LIKE '%".$tag."%' 
     ORDER BY postdate DESC $limit)
UNION 
(SELECT id, account_name, author, postdate, data from status_reply WHERE data LIKE '%".$tag."%' 
     ORDER BY postdate DESC $limit)");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use backquotes ` for field names instead of straight quotes '
2. Don't forget to quote `$tag` to protect from an SQL injection: [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
3. Remember, that is you want to search literally for LIKE wildcard characters "%", "_" as well as backslash. You need to escape them too, using: `$tag = addcslashes($tag, '\%_');`

---

```
$limit = "LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, "
(SELECT `status` as type from status WHERE data LIKE '%".$tag."%' 
     ORDER BY postdate DESC $limit)
UNION 
(SELECT `status_reply` as type from status_reply WHERE data LIKE '%".$tag."%' 
     ORDER BY postdate DESC $limit)");
```

Comment: I still have the same warning error: **Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\tag.php on line 82**

Comment: Code sanitation have been taken care of, the issue is the to solve the problem at hand. Nevertheless, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @MandeKira Try to run `print mysqli_error($db_conx);` after running `mysqli_query`

Comment: this is what I got : **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`status` as type from status WHERE data LIKE '%#mandekira%' ) UNION ALL ' at line 1**

Comment: @MandeKira Ah, gosh. Remove * before status and status_reply. I edited the answer.